# IP Address doesnt get passed with Squid as a reverse proxy

Tags: squid

Im using squid as a reverse proxy to host multiple web servers on one internet IP. It works fine and has been doing so for the past few months. I have just noticed that every request sent to my servers is logged as comming from the squid servers IP address.

Is there anyway to make squid pass the originating IP to the web servers?

Answer (score 2):

Squid uses the X-Forwarded-For header to pass the client IP through the reverse proxy.  You'll need to configure `forwarded_for on` for Squid, and tell your backend servers to log the new header.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things which I observed.

You need to enable `forward_for` on and if you `iptables MASQUERADE` rule for inbound traffic from your in interface you might need to remove it.

In my case I have a rule for outbound which causes the same I just removed that masquerade rule and things worked for me

Here is the rule.

```
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface $ETHERNET_INTERNET -j MASQUERADE
```

I just remove above masqured rule.